# Trundle Pillar(E) and Tahm Kenchs Ult?

Tags: league-of-legends

What happens when Trundle puts a pillar on Tahm Kenches ult destination, before the latter appears there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Valid for not only Trundle's Ice Pillar but also Anivia's Wall. It works on not only Tham Kench, but also on Pantheon (when he uses Skyfall), Vladimir (When he uses his blood pool) and Fizz (When he uses Playful - Without the second activation).

---

Trundle's Ice Pillar creates terrain which functions like a wall. When any champion is placed on the same place he is bumped into the easiest path. Tham Kench will still be slowed and pushed aside (if the pillar is directly on top of the zone he's coming in).

There's however an exception, when Tham Kench uses his ultimate on an already bad spot (Close to walls or next to a lot of minions), if you manage to place it at the right spot, you can trap Tham Kench, making him unable to move (or rather, he can move but he will be glitched out because the pathing system will just make him walk around himself).